# How to set text box value depending on value from combo box?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, combobox, textbox

I'm new at programming in C#, and now I'm making C# Windows form application.... 
I have a lots of questions, but lets start for now only with next one:

I would like to set values to text boxs, depending on selected value of combo box... any idea how to do that on easy way?

I have this application with Access database baza_artikala, which have 8tables, for my previous question I use tables Artikli and ZaprimljeniArtili. In one user control is DataGridView for ZaprimljeniArtili. There are text boxes ArticleNo, SIzeIndex and Tip kutije, and combo box EAN code.

Now I would like to fill those text boxes automaticly, depending on selected value from combo box EAN code.

For example: if ean cod is 0098090076418, values in text boxes should be ArticleNo 768595, SizeIndex 420 and Tip kutije B14.

All those values are supposed to be from Artikli table, and after they were setted they shoould write in data grid view(ZaprimljeniArtili table)...

Thank you for you help and sorry for my bad english.

If more information needed don't be a stranger, and conntact me.
:)

here is a preview of what I want it to do... bit.ly/12iSbmy
 and here's a full code that I'm using in that user control dropbox.com/s/25kqw4p1rjsx1o0/ZaprimljeniArtili.txt 
it's to long to be pasted here so I give You a txt file, I hope that's ok...

Comment: To avoid downvotes .. give some code you have ..

Comment: here is a preview of what I want it to do...
http://bit.ly/12iSbmy
and here's a full code that I'm using in that user control
https://www.dropbox.com/s/25kqw4p1rjsx1o0/ZaprimljeniArtili.txt
it's to long to be pasted here so I give You a txt file, I hope that ok...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`ComboBox`'s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) [`SelectedIndexChanged Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged.aspx).

First, double click on your combobox, which will automatically create the event handling for you, as well as take you to the method it will call.

You can use that method like this:

```
private void cmbMyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the selected text, you can also use SelectedIndex and SelectedValue
    string selectedText = cmbMyComboBox.SelectedText;

    switch (selectedText) // I'm using a case because I don't know your data hookup
    {
        case "some value":
            txtTextBox.Text = "some other value";
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

The key is using `SelectedText` (or one of the other variants) to get the selected item. You can then use it in your logic to populate other controls.

I don't know the exact way you are passing / collecting data, but this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: here is a preview of what I want it to do... bit.ly/12iSbmy 
and here's a full code that I'm using in that user control dropbox.com/s/25kqw4p1rjsx1o0/ZaprimljeniArtili.txt 
it's to long to be pasted here so I give You a txt file, I hope that ok...

Comment: @Andrej, So did my example help or hurt? I'm not going to write your code for you (unless you pay me), but it should have got you going in the right direction.

Comment: it got me in right way, thx